# Trying to locate a web element in d365 by xpath but it could find the element though it is a unique relative xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Trying to locate a web element in d365 by xpath but it could not find the element though it is a unique relative xpath. Anyone please help on that.

```
//div[6 and @data-dyn-rowid='2']//input[@name='ONGSROActivityLine_Quantity']
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sWdl.png

Comment: are you sure whatever this element exist sin the dom when you try to locate it?

Comment: yeah it is in the DOM @ZacharyCraig

Comment: @mshravangoud Can you give us the html code of that element?